# Why cant I just download Firefox and run it?

Tags: software-installation

Previously I was able to just click "Download Firefox" and it would "do its thing" but now it comes as a tar.bz2 file, which I have no idea how to deal with. Are geeks just getting lazy or just trying to make the less commuter literate feel stupid?

Answer (score 1):

You have some options for installing software. To install Firefox (which should have been installed already with most Ubuntu distros) you can open a Terminal session and enter:

`sudo apt-get install firefox`

Alternatively, you can use a package manager like Synaptic to download and install Firefox for you. Either method will draw from the supported repositories.